# Find angle $\alpha$ in $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

As title suggests, the goal is to find $\alpha$ from the given $\triangle ABC$ with some given angles and sides. I'm posting this here to look for better solutions, as my own, which I'll post as well, is rather complicated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a simpler solution.

[image]

First step: Let us establish that

$$DA=DC\tag{1}$$

With notations of the figure, in isosceles triangle $ABD$:

$$\gamma = 180°-2(7\alpha - \beta)$$

Let us write now that the sum of angles in triangle $ABC$ is $180°$:

$$7 \alpha + [180°-2(7\alpha - \beta)+2 \alpha]+[2\alpha+\alpha]=180°$$

As a consequence $\beta = \alpha$ ; therefore triangle $ADC$ is isosceles ; as a consequence, we can conclude to (1).

---

Second step: Due to (1), $D$ is the center of the circumscribed circle to triangle $ABC$. The central angle $\widehat{BDC}$ being the double of the inscribed angle $\widehat{BAC}$, ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)), we have:

$$\widehat{BDC}=14 \alpha $$

As the sum of angles in triangle $BDC$ is 180°, we can write:

$$2 \alpha + 2 \alpha + 14 \alpha = 180°.$$

Conclusion:

$$\alpha = 10°$$

Comment: That's incorrect. For this to work, you must prove that point D is the circumcenter of triangle ABC. In other words, you must prove that a segment DA=AB=BD=DC. One cannot make that assumption without proving it. I proved it in my own solution

Comment: You are right. I am going to correct this "solution" for it being a ... solution.

Comment: Complete solution given.

Comment: Nice one. Though, I'm curious, you could have proved that alpha=beta and then deduced that DA=DC without having to claim (1) first right?

Comment: No, in fact I couldn't have proven this in this order. I still don't see clearly how I have made the assumption that $ABD$ is equilateral...  based on no arguing, as you have made immediately the remark.

Comment: Oh, that remark for when the solution was incomplete. And what I'm talking about is something like this. Let's say you didn't make claim (1) but simply drew segment DA as in your diagram, and called angle DAC beta, following the exact same steps in your solution, it is possible to prove that alpha=beta and then deduce that DA=DC. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 7):

I think my solution is quite simple. Since $\triangle BDC$ is isosceles, it follows that $\angle BCD = \angle CBD = 2 \alpha$, and as such, $\angle BCA = 3\alpha$. We then compute that
$$
\angle ABD = 180 - \angle CBD - \angle BCA - \angle BAC = 180 - 2\alpha - 3\alpha - 7\alpha = 180 - 12 \alpha.
$$
Because also $\triangle ABD$ is isosceles, we decude from this that
$$
\angle BAD = \frac{180 - \angle ABD}{2} = 6\alpha.
$$
In particular, we find that $\angle CAD = 7\alpha - 6\alpha = \alpha$. This implies that also $\triangle CDA$ is isosceles; whence $|AD| = |DC| = |DB| = |BA|$. It follows that $\triangle BDA$ is even equilateral and as such, its angles are all $60^{\circ}$. Hence $6\alpha = 60^{\circ}$, and thus $\alpha = 10^{\circ}$.

Comment: Amazing. I knew there was a much shorter method and there it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So, this'll be my approach to this problem. I'll add an explanation of the process as well as my motivation for certain decisions as best as I can:

[image]

1.) Label the $\triangle ABC$ and mark all the appropriate angles and points, it is already given that $AB=BD=DC$. Locate point $E$ outside $\triangle ABC$ and connect it with point
$C$ such that $CE=DC=BD=AB$. It is obvious that $\triangle DCE$ is isosceles, therefore $\angle CDE=\angle CED=\alpha$.

2.) Connect points $A$ and $E$ via segment $AE$ to form
$\triangle AEB$. Locate another point $F$ outside $\triangle AEB$ and connect it to $E$ via $EF$ such that $\angle CEF=2\alpha$ and segment $EF=CB$, next join $C$ and $F$ via $CF$. Notice that $\triangle ECF$ is congruent to $\triangle CDB$ via the SAS property. Therefore, $CF=CE=DC=BD=AB$ and $\angle CFE=2\alpha$. Connect point $F$ with $B$ via
$BF$ to form $\triangle BFC$. Notice that
$\angle FCB=4\alpha$ via the external angle theorem. Further, connect points $A$ and $F$ via segment $AF$.

3.) Notice that $\angle ACF=\angle CAB=7\alpha$. Also notice that, as established before, $CF=AB$. This implies that
$\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle FCA$ are also congruent via the SAS property. This proves that segment $BC=AF=FE$. This also implies that $\triangle AFE$ is isosceles. Now, notice that quadrilateral $ABFC$ has two equal diagonals $AF$ and $BC$, and two equal non-parallel sides $CF$ and $AB$. This proves that this quadrilateral is an isosceles trapezoid, which means that it is in fact a cyclic quadrilateral.

4.) Above implies that $\angle FAB=\angle BCF=4\alpha$. This implies that $\angle FAC=\angle BAC-\angle BAF$. Therefore,
$\angle FAC=7\alpha-4\alpha=3\alpha$. Notice that this means that, in the isosceles triangle $\triangle AFE$,
$\angle FAC=\angle FCD=3\alpha$. This proves that $\angle DEA=\angle CAE=\alpha$. This also proves that segment $AC=DE$. Notice that this implies $\triangle DEF$ is congruent to $\triangle FAC$ and $\triangle ABC$ via the SAS property. This also implies that segment $DF=CF=CE=DC=BD=AB$. But notice that this means $\triangle DCF$ is equilateral with
$\angle DCF=6\alpha$. This means that $6\alpha=60$, therefore $\alpha=10$.

Answer (score 0):

**Law of Sine on ΔABC**

$\displaystyle \frac{AB}{\sin(2α+α)} = \frac{BC = 2\,BD\,\cos(2α)}{\sin(7α)}$

Given $AB=BD$, it simplified to:

$\sin(7α) = 2\sin(3α)\cos(2α) = \sin(5α) + \sin(α)$

$\sin(α) = \sin(7α) - \sin(5α) = 2\cos(6α)\sin(α)$

$\sin(α)≠0$, otherwise no triangle $\displaystyle \quad → \cos(6α) = \frac{1}{2} \quad → α = \frac{60°}{6} = 10°$

Comment: cos(6α) = 1/2 have many solutions, but ∠A = 7α < 180°.  Others, example, α=70°, are no good.